# Ensuring div are placed below each other after the top div grows in size

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have two divs that represent a list of elements the user can click on on a search bar, followed by a "Done" button.

```
<div class="dropdown col" id="dropdown-search-id">
  <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="inputSearch" placeholder="Search for a term ">


    <div class="col dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="inputSearch">
      <div id="search_list_container">
        <ul id="inputSearchEntries">
          <li id="searching_li" style="visibility:hidden">
            <img src="{{static_dir}}/loader.gif" alt="Loading" style="width:15%"/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      
      <div id="doneSearchButton" class="d-flex justify-content-end"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
      </div>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever the user starts typing, there are a number of `<li>` elements that appear with an autocomplete function (that is, they are appended between the `<ul>` tag,  but the position of the "Done" button is messed up, as it does not stay at the bottom, that is, below the list elements.

[image]

How can I keep the button always at the bottom of the list, regardless of how many elements there are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example below. I used your code, added a few `<li>` items, the `data-bs-toggle` and a class on the `<ul>` list so no bullets appear, and the buttons is where it should be.

So if your problem isn't solved with my example, post the full example of the dropdown, with the search results and including any custom CSS.

Other options:

- Use the helper class `float-end` instead of using flex.
- Place the btn inside the list: `<ul><li>..</li><li><btn></li></ul>`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown col" id="dropdown-search-id">
  <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="inputSesarch" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" placeholder="Search for a term ">
  <div class="col dropdown-menu form-control" aria-labelledby="inputSearch">
    <div id="search_list_container">
     <ul class="list-group" id="inputSearchEntries">    
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First result</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another result</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some other result</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="doneSearchButton" class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Done</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay getting back to this.

I ended up creating a nested `<ul>`, where the top one contains two elements, the first being the `<ul>` I had and the second one is the `doneSearchButton`. This always preserves the order as intended.